# Relación condicional Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class BiometricEmployer extends Model
{
    protected $table="biometric_employers";
    protected $fillable=['bag_number','biometric_id','employer_id'];
    public function marcajes(){
        return $this->hasMany(CheckBio::class,'bag_number_employers','bag_number');
    }
}
```

y

```
class CheckBio extends Model
{
   protected $fillable=[
        'bag_number_employers','date','biometric_id'
   ];
}
```

Donde `BiometricEmployer` tiene una relación de muchos a muchos con `CkeckBio`, pero quisiera que esta relación sea con dos llaves `BiometricEmployer('bag_number')` con `CkeckBio('bag_number_employers')` y  `BiometricEmployer('biometric_id')` con `CkeckBio('biometric_id')`.

Intenté algo como esto:

```
public function marcajes(){
    return $this->hasMany(CheckBio::class,'bag_number_employers','bag_number')->where('biometric_id',$this->biometric_id);
}
```

Pero `$this->biometric_id` siempre me da `null` y no sé si estuviera bien hacer ese `where` ahí.

Básicamente busco hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
$resultado=\DB::select("select cb.date from biometric_employers be, check_bios cb where be.biometric_id=cb.biometric_id and be.bag_number=cb.bag_number_employers and be.employer_id=? and DATE(cb.date)=? and TIME(cb.date)>? and TIME(cb.date)<?",[$id,$date,$h1,$h2]);
```

Donde `$id` pertenece a un empleado, `$date` es una fecha, y `$h1`-`$h2` determinan un rango de horas. Esa es la consulta que estoy manejando, pero gustaría tenerla en ORM puro de laravel(esto solo para mantener código en orden).

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer dos relaciones independientes entre dichos modelos o intentas filtrar una relación? No me queda muy claro lo que quieres lograr. Por favor agrega el código completo de los dos modelos para tener una mejor idea y si puedes, amplia la explicación de lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Quiero una relación con dos llaves foraneas. Nada mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent no tiene soporte para trabajar con tablas que tienen claves primarias compuestas. Ya se habló por github muchas veces sobre este tema.
La única opción es crearte un método simple a mano.

Enlace de GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/1909

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que está escrito en la pregunta y en el comentario, deseas crear una relación de muchos a muchos con dos llaves foráneas, para lo cual asumo que tienes una tabla pivote o intermedia y las relaciones serían así:

En el modelo BiometricEmployer:

```
public function marcajes1()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(CheckBio::class, 'bag_number_employers', 'bag_number');
}

public function marcajes2()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(CheckBio::class, 'biometric_id', 'biometric_id');
}
```

En el modelo CheckBio sería algo similar:

```
public function bioEmployer1()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(BiometricEmployer::class, 'bag_number', 'bag_number_employers');
}

public function bioEmployer2()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(BiometricEmployer::class, 'biometric_id', 'biometric_id');
}
```

Comment: hola @Shaz, pues de "muchos a muchos" seria la idea, el problema es que la tabla `checkBios` es una tabla que viene desde un lector biometrico, razon por la cual la normalizacion de la BdD quedo asi. y no tengo una tabla pivote, pero me diste una buena idea gracias.

Comment: La verdad es que sin ver los modelos completos y sin una explicación más detallada es complicado ayudar.

Comment: estan los dos modelos completos, la verdad y explico a detalle lo que quiero conseguir, no se que mas quieres, ahora si no entiendes no coloques -1.